How to use BigQuery function NORMALIZE for non-literal queries?
I have a table in BigQuery with a string column that contains strings with unicode for special characters.
I want to decode them using function NORMALIZE but it seems that it doesn't work for non-literal queries.
If I write:
SELECT NORMALIZE('ccpl\u00e8-011-ne32', NFC) AS normalized_name;

It works, giving:
ccplè-011-ne32

But if I apply that to a column:
SELECT NORMALIZE(page_location, NFC) AS aaa FROM `prj.ds.table1` 

it doesn't work. It returns:
ccpl\u00e8-011-ne32

Why is that?
Thanks
